# Learning Python. Having trouble with the tkinter widget.Grid manager and adding a scrollbar to a listbox widget

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox, grid, pack

I got most of this attached code from another question.  I'm using Python 3.8.  It would seem that the Pack Manager will easily add a scrollbar widget to a listbox widget.  However, I'm using the Grid Manager.  I can't get a vertical scrollbar to work properly.

When you run this code,  a vertical scrollbar will appear, but it is not physically attached to the listbox widget properly.  BTW: I got the horizontal scrollbar working without a problem.

```
from tkinter import *

master = Tk()

listbox = Listbox(master)

scrollbar = Scrollbar(master, orient=VERTICAL)
scrollbar.grid(row=2, rowspan=50, column=40, sticky=N + S)

for i in range(50):
    listbox.insert(END, str(i))
listbox.grid(sticky="news")

scrollbar.config(command=listbox.yview)

mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: put `Listbox` and `Scrollbar` to `Frame` using `pack()` and then put this `Frame` to window using `grid()`

Comment: you don't have to use `rowspan=50` for `Scrollbar` - `Listbox` uses only one row even if you put 50 lines of text in `Listbox`.

Comment: use `listbox.grid(row=2, ...)`

Comment: you forgot `tk.Listbox(..., yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)`

Comment: I don't know why you tried to add image to my answer. I add it to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `row=` and `column=` for both elements - to put in the same row and different columns.

You forgot `tk.Listbox(..., yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)`

You don't have to use `rowspan=50` for `Scrollbar` - `Listbox` uses only one row even if you insert 50 lines of text.

```
import tkinter as tk # `import *` is not preferred (see PEP8)

master = tk.Tk()

scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(master, orient='vertical')
scrollbar.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky='ns')

listbox = tk.Listbox(master, yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
for i in range(50):
    listbox.insert('end', str(i))
listbox.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky="news")

scrollbar.config(command=listbox.yview)

master.mainloop()
```

[PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Answer (score 0):

If you think `pack()` is more easier, then you can `pack` the `Listbox` and `Scrollbar` inside a `Frame` and then use `grid()` on the frame:

```
import tkinter as tk

master = tk.Tk()

frame = tk.Frame(master)
frame.grid(row=0, column=0) # set row and column to the desired position

listbox = tk.Listbox(frame)
listbox.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)

scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(frame, orient=tk.VERTICAL, command=listbox.yview)
scrollbar.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)

listbox.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
for i in range(50):
    listbox.insert(tk.END, str(i))

master.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your example which mixes pack and grid managers works and gives the appropriate scrollbars.  However, I've read that one should not use both managers in the same code.

Comment: You cannot mix `pack` and `grid` in **same** container.  In my example, `frame` is the container of the `listbox` and `scrollbar`.  And `master` is the container of `frame`.